# Are video games permissible?

Tags: halal-haram

Are video games permissible? 
You act out a story, listen to music, and sometimes worship false gods within them.

Comment: I can't imagine a game where you worship false gods to be consistent in any form with Islam. Frankly speaking, if you aren't put off by such idolatry in the game, you'd better revise your faith.

Answer (score 2):

Video games of themselves are permissible. However, it's the haram elements you find in video games (violence,magic etc) that makes the specific games which contain them impermissible.It also becomes impermissible if they waste time and keep you from doing what is obligatory in Islam.
https://islamqa.info/en/2898